# Range standardize a complete matrix R

Tags: r, matrix, standardized

I'm working with pairwise distances in the format of a hollow matrix of 45 rows and 45 columns in which the upper and lower triangles are mirrored. I need to range standardize my entire matrix so that all values lie between 0 and 1. I've tried it with `decostand(mat, method="range")` but since the columns are not independent of each other, this does not return the correct values. The upper triangle is no longer mirroring the lower triangle. I presume this is some sort of issue with centering or scaling the data?

Here's a bit of sample code to work with:

```
x<-c(0,5,4,7,8,
  5,0,8,2,1,
  4,8,0,3,2,
  7,2,3,0,4,
  8,1,2,4,0)

mat<-matrix(x,nrow=5,ncol=5,byrow=TRUE)

mat2<-decostand(mat,method="range")
```

and an example of how I would like the matrix to look once standardized..

```
  V1   V2   V3   V4   V5
1 0    0.6  0.5  0.9  1
2 0.6  0    1    0.3  0.1
3 0.5  1    0    0.4  0.3
4 0.9  0.3  0.4  0    0.5
5 1    0.1  0.3  0.5  0
```

Is there a way of doing it without converting my data to a vector to standardise it and then back to a matrix? considering that I have a few matrices with dimensions up to 90 x 90 I would rather do it in one step, since then there's less chance of my data being mixed up by columns, because the ID is quite important.

Thanks!

Comment: try `mat/max(mat)`

Comment: GENIUS! and a simple answer too...exactly what I was looking for. Thanks @mtoto !